# How to convert a DependencyObject into an AutomationElement?

Tags: c#, wpf, type-conversion, visual-tree, visualtreehelper

I am traversing a WPF application through its VisualTree, using the [VisualTreeHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper(v=vs.110).aspx), which is returning [DependencyObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
for(int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(rootObject); i++) {
    var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(rootObject, i);
}
```

However, once i find the object i'm looking for (in this case its a button) i need to "press"/invoke it. I've successfully invoked a button using an [InvokePattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.invokepattern(v=vs.110).aspx) on an [AutomationElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
private void ClickBtn(AutomationElement btnElement) {
    InvokePattern btnPattern = btnElement.GetCurrentPattern(
        InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern;
    btnPattern.Invoke();
}
```

So the problem stands: How do i convert a DependencyObjects into an AutomationElement? 
Or: How do i invoke a DependancyObject? 
Or: How do i create an AutomationElement that points to the same WPF element as a given DependencyObjects dose?

**Edit1:** 
I've found that i can convert the DependancyObject to a Control.

```
var childVisual = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(rootObject, i);
var childInstance = childVisual as Control;
```

However the problem stands: How do i invoke a Control? 
Or: How do i convert a Control into an AutomationElement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i could cast the AutomationElement to a ButtonBase and call its "OnLoad" method through reflection:

```
var childVisual = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(rootObject, i);
var btnToInvoke = childVisual as ButtonBase; 
MethodInfo clickMethodInfo = typeof(Button).GetMethod("OnClick",
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
clickMethodInfo.Invoke(btnToInvoke, new object[] {});
```